# I can not load sf in docker

Tags: r, docker, gdal, r-sf

I'm deploying an application (on docker) that is totally dependent on `sf` but I'm having trouble loading it into docker :

```
FROM rocker/shiny

#Make a directory in the container
RUN mkdir /home/shiny-app

RUN R -e "install.packages('sf')"

RUN R -e "library('sf')"

COPY . /home/shiny-app/
```

This is the error message I received. I have no idea what caused this error. Probably GDAL?
I need help to solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: For future questions, it is generally preferred to _not_ have just screenshots/images of code, data, and errors, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). An image is fine so long as you back it up with highlighting the text in that console window, copying it, and pasting it into your question in a [code block]. Often doing that precludes the need for a screenshot, though not always.

Comment: FYI, the `library('sf')` should not be in your `Dockerfile`, it should be in your app `.R` files, such as your `global.R` file. I think you added it here primarily to have a small reproducible dockerfile (thank you!), but in case you weren't aware, calling that in your dockerfile has no effect on the app/code deployed within the image. (Well, unless you are for some reason including a `.Rdata` file in your image, which I don't encourage ...)

Comment: Allow me to thank you most sincerely. You have just added tons of knowledge to the little I had. Yes indeed, I have ```library (sf)``` in my global.R file where all my dependencies are. It's the same error I get. I just wanted to highlight the part where there was a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to add R packages to a new OS running R, you need to be aware of any underlying OS packages that are required. In this case, reading `sf`'s [`DESCRIPTION`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/index.html), we see

```
SystemRequirements: GDAL (>= 2.0.1), GEOS (>= 3.4.0), PROJ (>= 4.8.0), sqlite3
```

It's not always intuitive how to know what these labels mean. One place you might look for a hint about this is Posit's [Package Manager](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/packages/overview?search=sf), which lists the following OS requirements on Ubuntu 22.04 (on which `rocker/shiny` is based).

```
apt-get install -y libgdal-dev
apt-get install -y gdal-bin
apt-get install -y libgeos-dev
apt-get install -y libproj-dev
apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev
apt-get install -y libssl-dev
apt-get install -y libudunits2-dev
```

Many of those are likely already present.

First, let me reproduce the problem:

```bash
$ docker build -t quux .
$ docker run -it --rm quux R --quiet
> library("sf")
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/units/libs/units.so':
  libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Through experience, I know that Jammy (22.04) needs these packages for R's `sf` package, add these lines somewhere in your `Dockerfile`:

```
# ...
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y libproj22 libudunits2-0 libgdal30 && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN R -e "install.packages('sf')"
```

Notes:

1. Whether or not you join those with previous  `apt` and `install.packages(..)` commands are up to you.
2. I encourage you to review https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/instructions/ for "best practices", especially when installing OS-level packages, attempting to balance that with image size (ergo the `rm -rf` command).

It now works:

```bash
$ docker build -t quux .
$ docker run -it --rm quux R --quiet
> library("sf")
Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much  @r2evans!!! I have deployed my applicatio